# Conditional Expectation of a continuous random variable with respect to an event

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ a continuous random variable in $(\Omega, F, P)$ and $A \in F$. Does someone has the proof for the result below ? (for discrete variables, it is trivial)

$E[X|A]=\frac{E[X1_{A}]}{P(A)}$

Comment: For any single event $A$, $\sigma(A) = \{\varnothing, A, A^c, \Omega\}.$ Let $Y = \mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(A)]$. Since $Y$ is $\sigma(A)$-measurable, you must have $Y(\omega) = \alpha \mathbf{1}_A(\omega) + \beta \mathbf{1}_{A^c}(\omega)$ for some constants $\alpha, \beta.$ Further, since $\int Y\mathbf{1}_A = \int X\mathbf{1}_A,$ you get $\alpha P(A) = \mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_A]$, and similarly for $\beta.$ Conclude by noting that for a single event $A,$ $\mathbb{E}[X|A] := \mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(A)] \mathbf{1}_A.$